# Appcelerator Titanium License

Tags: android, ios, licensing, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-mobile

So I am reading [this](http://www.appcelerator.com/company/agreements/) and now I don't know anything. Could someone in 2,3 sentences tell me the main things about Appcelerator Titanium license. Things like: Distributing apps on App Store and Android Market. Do I need to pay anything to Appcelerator for my apps etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pretty straight forward, build your app.. publish to app store

dont make it more complicated than that... there are THOUSANDS of apps in the app store from Appcelerator, dont be distracted by the noise.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure before I start developing. Thank you.

Comment: how's your experience. What sort of limitations Titanium have. I want to start a project, i need some suggestions regarding cross platforms.

Comment: look at my profile and you can see my experience with the platform? You profile is empty and you are on here anonymously so I don't know if this is noise or are you serious